# Find and Replace Youtube url

Tags: php, string, url, replace, youtube

Ive got a form, where users can add videos to a profile field. What I am trying to do is make the video auto play. However Im struggling with youtube url, I know most users will just copy the URL from their browser.

So ive got this

```
<iframe src="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wpcf-item-video', true ); ?>" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

It fetches the url fine
for example

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SabxJ0nqKlE
```

Now I need to turn the `watch?v=` to `/embed/`

Any advice on how I can accomplish this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do

```
<?php
$url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wpcf-item-video', true );
$my_var = '/embed/';

$url = str_replace("watch?v=", $my_var, $url );

 ?>
<iframe src="<?php echo $url ?>" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_replace` just do this:

`str_replace('watch?v=', '/embed/', $myUrl)`

then put the url in the frame

Comment: How would I implement this?

Comment: Do you mean after putting the url in the frame search for it and replace it ?
if that tell me and I will edit the answer or add new one